# Symfony Form Event POST_SUBMIT not working

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, events

I am actually trying to make a post_submit working on a non-entity-mapped form, the goal is to update the content (coming from an API) of a a city select field when i change my zip code input field.

The problem is even if i dump_die a value in the post_submit event it does not show it, like it's never taking in account.

Here is what i have done so far :

My controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(EligibilityType::class);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
    }

    return $this->render('eligibility/eligibility.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
```

My form with the events (also where i retrieve api datas) :

```
->add('postalCode', IntegerType::class, [
            'label' => 'Code postal',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Ex : 75002',
                'class' => 'form-control eligibility_postalcode'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Ville',
            'placeholder' => 'Veuillez saisir un code postal',
            'attr' => [
                'id' => 'eligibility_city'
            ]
        ])

$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, $postalCode = null) {
        $towns[] = null === $postalCode ? [] : $this->eligibility->getAlphaLinkTown('fr', $postalCode);
        $form->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Sélectionner votre ville...',
            'choices' => $towns,
            'choice_label' => function($choice) {
                return $choice;
            }
        ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data);
        }
    );

    $builder->get('postalCode')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $postalCode = $event->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $postalCode);
        }
    );
}
```

My AJAX :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
let $postalCode = $('#eligibility_postalCode');
$postalCode.on('change', function() {
  let $form = $(this).closest('form');
  let data = {};
  data[$postalCode.attr('name')] = $postalCode.val();
  console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
    url : '/eligibility',
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    data : data,
    success: function(html) {
      console.log(html)
      $('#eligibility_city').replaceWith(
          $(html.responseText).find('#eligibility_city')
      );
    }
  });
});
```

});

Thank you in advance for all the help you can provide,

Val

Comment: what tell the logs? have you something in the network tab of the console with F12 ?

Comment: Hi, the logs tell nothing, it does not pass into post_submit event, even dump are not shown.

Comment: May be you are missing  $form->handleRequest($request)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->handleRequest($request)` is missing in your controller. Adding it will allow your controller to handle the difference between GET and POST request. Take some time to read https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#handling-form-submissions if needed.

It should help you understand a bit more why your POST_SUBMIT event is not executed by your form.

Comment: Sorry for the late approval answer, it actually turned out the handleRequest was missing, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` event is dispatched after the `Form::submit()` once the model and view data have been denormalized.

It can be used to fetch data after denormalization.

Comment: Hi, does that mean i have to submit the form with JS each time i change my input value ?

Comment: In your case yes. But I would suggest please use `PRE_SUBMIT` event instead of `POST_SUBMIT`. you can easily get updated value in `PRE_SUBMIT` event before form submit.

Comment: I tried with PRE_SUBMIT and "$form.attr('action')" as AJAX url param but the problem is still the same, i can't even display my "dd();" on PRE_SUBMIT when i change my input value.

Comment: Please don't submit form using ajax function. Using AJAX, you have to change field value only and then same logic you have to implement in Form using `PRE_SET_DATA` and `PRE_SUBMIT` event to handle changed data from Ajax.